# LVDT output type concept

Tags: ac, sensor, dc

[image: LVDT with bipolar DC output]

Hey all.
I know the concept about LVDT and how it works, but I struggle to understand a minor thing.

why we need the output of LVDT to be DC? is there any specific reason or just because it is easier to determine the displacement direction and value using a DC voltage than an AC signal?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

A DC voltage related to position is much easier for the instrumentation to handle. You can easily scale it, offset it, feed it into a PID controller etc.

Unless you're running a Selsyn, processing a complex AC signal is a pain.